# How to send more than one AJAX request to one PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send multiple AJAX requests to one PHP file, because I am creating a big project and in the index page there is a lot of buttons which have different functionality.

It would be very bad to make for each button a file with PHP.

This is my AJAX code:

```
        $('#check').click(function(){
            var val = $(this).filter('input:checked').val();                
            $.ajax({
                url: './process/upload.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'check': val},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

In the PHP file I can't add `if(isset($_POST['check'])){}` It won't work but if I write it like this `if(isset($_POST)){}`

To do it like `if(isset($_POST)){}` it will cause some errors if I add `if(isset($_POST)){}` for another button

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" class="check" id="check" checked>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not include a "source" parameter? e.g.

```
data: {check: val, source: 'from_button_A' }
```

and then you check `if($_POST['source'] == 'from_button_A')` and go from there.

Comment: if($_POST['source']) the source parameter can be anything or what?

Comment: it's whatever you're passing from the JS-side to identify where this particular ajax request is coming from.

Comment: It can be like this: data: {check: val, check: 'from_button_A' } Or it will be source, sorry for asking to much

Comment: it's `{key:value}`, and `$_POST['key']`. so `$_POST['check']` and `$_POST['source']` for this particular example.